# How can i make the data transfer between esi server and computer faster on LAN

Tags: networking, router, vmware, lan, switch

My LAN speed is very less. Even downloading from Internet is fater "1.5MBPS" and from LAN its `300KBPS`.

MY setup is like this

`Netgear wireless Router --------DESKTOP`

`Netgar ------wireless bridge ----LAN cable to ESXI on same Subnet`

Now if i upload stuff from DESKTOP ot ESXI via vmware vsphere client then speed is about 300KBPS

Is there any way to make the LAN speed fast especially for transfering between ESXI and any laptop. maybe using some switch so that trnasfer does not go via wireless

Comment: If  you are able to connect the desktop and ESXi server with a switch and pair of patch cables, then yes, that will almost certainly improve your speed.  Was that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Slartibartfast If want to achieve maximum LAN speed, can you tell me what type of switch i will need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether there are spare ports on both machines, you might be able to make do with just a crossover cable, technically.

But if you want a switch, or you want to link more than those two machines on your wired network, you'd look for a switch that had a speed equal to or better than the lowest speed of (your ESXi server, and your Desktop).  This would likely be 100Mbps, or 1Gbps.  Either should let you transfer faster than 300kbps.

For configuration, you'll want to configure the additional interface to be a network distinct from the wireless network.  E.g. if your wireless network is 192.168.1.0/24, you will want to use a different network, like 192.168.2.0/24, and assign IP addresses from that network, e.g.:

- ESXi host: 192.168.2.10
- Desktop: 192.168.2.11

You would then connect to the ESXi host using the IP address 192.168.2.10 from the desktop to establish a fast connection.

Comment: If i use different subnet then what should be the gateway of those so that they can connect to internet as well through netgear router

Comment: There is one default gateway per computer, and it should still be your Netgear for both computers so that they both work with or without the new cable.